# How to delay subtitles

Tags: c++

I have to write a code for delaying subtitles.

I have to open .srt file change all the time for some time and save it in another file.
I know how to open file and copy all to other file.

For example if i open "Subtitle.srt" and then write the name of output file "output" i would get the copied content of "Subtitle.srt" to "outputSubtitle.srt".

This is ok but I dont know how to delay time for instance if I input "10"

Original Subbtitle.srt 
00:00:01,067 --> 00:00:03,963
and then I enter 10
outputSubtitle.srt
00:00:11,067 --> 00:00:13,963

I have to change all the times.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "cstdlib"
#include "fstream"
#include "string"

 using namespace std;

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 ifstream input; //input

 char input_file[32]; //names of input and output


  cout << "Enter name of input fille: "; ///user gives names of input
  cin >> input_file;

 input.open(input_file);
 if (!input.good()){
cout << "File " << input_file << " dosen't exist." << endl;
return 1;
}


string row;
while (!input.eof()){    
getline(input, row);

cout << row << endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but what do subtitles have to do with this code?

Comment: So are the times in that xx:xx:xx,xxx format?

Comment: You're coding in C++ not C, so take advantage of it's features. Use `std::string` to avoid dangerous potential buffer overflow issues  e.g. if the user types a filename bigger than 31 characters (which by the way, is a totally unreasonable number - modern OS's typically allow much longer filenames, and ones that don't are typically much less). Also, your use of `eof` [is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong), and `system("pause")` [should be avoided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the string format is `hour:minute:second,millisecond`. Well, this function takes a string as an initial time, and an int amount to add in seconds. It probably breaks if you give it a negative time, but any reasonable positive time works just fine. It returns the output string, so you can juts print that where the old string was.

```
string add(string str, int amount) {
    int vals[8];
    sscanf(str.c_str(), "%u:%u:%u,%u --> %u:%u:%u,%u",
    &vals[0], &vals[1], &vals[2], &vals[3],
    &vals[4], &vals[5], &vals[6], &vals[7]);

    vals[2] += amount;
    vals[6] += amount;
    while((vals[2]>=60) || (vals[1]>=60) ||
          (vals[6]>=60) || (vals[5]>=60)) {
        if(vals[2] >= 60) {
            vals[2] -= 60;
            vals[1]++;
        }
        if(vals[6] >= 60) {
            vals[6] -= 60;
            vals[5]++;
        }
        if(vals[1] >= 60) {
            vals[1] -= 60;
            vals[0]++;
        }
        if(vals[5] >= 60) {
            vals[5] -= 60;
            vals[4]++;
        }
    }
    string out;
    out.resize(str.length());
    int n = sprintf(&out[0], "%02u:%02u:%02u,%03u --> %02u:%02u:%02u,%03u", 
    vals[0], vals[1], vals[2], vals[3],
    vals[4], vals[5], vals[6], vals[7]);

    return out;
};
```